# when I call this function "showMe(calcTotal(myNumberArray));" in the console it works, but it doesn't work when called in the code

Tags: javascript

when I call this function "showMe(calcTotal(myNumberArray));" in the console it works, but it doesn't work when called in the code. Sorry if my code herts you eyes or doesn't make since. it's supposed to calculate the total. I would like to know why the browser doesn't see the invocation or why the value is not displayed on the screen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>

 </style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="hit">hit</button>
  <div id="number"></div>
  <div id="arrayOutput"></div>
  <div id="someId"></div>
  <div id="out2"></div>
<script>
 //Services helper functon
  var myNumberArray = [];

document.getElementById('hit').onclick = function randomNumber() {
 var card = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
 document.getElementById('number').innerHTML=card;
myNumberArray.push(card);
var number =myNumberArray.value;
  var arrayOutput = document.getElementById('number');
var someId = document.getElementById('someId');
someId.innerHTML = myNumberArray;

  };
//var output = myNumberArray = calcTotal(list);
function calcTotal(myNumberArray) {
 var total = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < myNumberArray.length; i++){
  total += myNumberArray[i];
 }
 return total;
 

}
//document.getElementById('out2').innerHTML = out2;
   what = calcTotal(myNumberArray);
var what= calcTotal(myNumberArray);

function showMe(VAL) {
 var parent = document.getElementById('out2');
 parent.innerHTML = VAL;
}
showMe(calcTotal(myNumberArray));


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you click on `hit` button before trying on console? try without button click on console to see if it still works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the total value on click of the button, then you need to call `showMe(calcTotal(myNumberArray));` inside the click handler.

```js
//Services helper functon
var myNumberArray = [];

document.getElementById('hit').onclick = function randomNumber() {
  var card = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = card;
  myNumberArray.push(card);
  var number = myNumberArray.value;
  var arrayOutput = document.getElementById('number');
  var someId = document.getElementById('someId');
  someId.innerHTML = myNumberArray;
  showMe(calcTotal(myNumberArray));

};
//var output = myNumberArray = calcTotal(list);
function calcTotal(myNumberArray) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myNumberArray.length; i++) {
    total += myNumberArray[i];
  }
  return total;


}
//document.getElementById('out2').innerHTML = out2;
what = calcTotal(myNumberArray);
var what = calcTotal(myNumberArray);

function showMe(VAL) {
  var parent = document.getElementById('out2');
  parent.innerHTML = VAL;
}

showMe(calcTotal(myNumberArray));
```

```html
<button id="hit">hit</button>
<div id="number"></div>
<div id="arrayOutput"></div>
<div id="someId"></div>
<div id="out2"></div>
```